# PXE boot a computer using Ironic Bifrost

Tags: centos, ansible, pxe, openstack

I am using Openstack Ironic standalone using Bifrost. I followed this link link https://docs.openstack.org/bifrost/latest/install/index.html#introduction to install Bifrost on CentOS system in VirtualBox. As mentioned to edit the `./playbooks/inventory/group_vars/*` files, what do I need to specify in the target file? A sample will be very helpful.

I am using two VirtualBox interfaces; one is NAT and the other is a Host-only adapter that is assigned static IP 192.168.56.101.